# Python: Accessing dictionary using variable as the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to access a dictionary by using a variable that I've set previously.

```
myvar1 = 1
mydict =  {'1': ['apple', 20, 80, 40],
    '2': ['orange', 81, 400, 100]}

myvar2 = mydict[myvar1][0]
print(myvar2)
```

This gives me KeyError: 1

I've also tried

```
myvar2 = mydict['myvar1'][0]
```

This gives me KeyError: 'myvar1'

Clearly I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myvar1` is an integer and `mydict` uses strings as keys. Either change `myvar1` to be a string or change the dictionary to use integers as keys.

```
myvar1 = 1
mydict = {1: ['apple', 20, 80, 40],
          2: ['orange', 81, 400, 100]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myvar1 = '1'
```

in your first statement. The `1` you're using is an integer, and not a character as in `'1'`:

```
In [1]: 1=='1'
Out[1]: False

In [2]: str(1)=='1'
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myvar1 = 1
mydict =  {1: ['apple', 20, 80, 40],
           2: ['orange', 81, 400, 100]}

myvar2 = mydict[myvar1][0]
print(myvar2)
```

First of all, your "keys" in `mydict` was **strings** and not **integers** while `myvar = 1` **is** a integer so you need to keep the keys as integers as well for comparison. Unify your variable standards!

Comment: `mydict[myvar1][0]` is accessing the 0th element in the list, "apple". It isn't a dictionary key.